# Excel VBA Find method goes wrong?

Tags: vba, excel, find

**My Sheet**

I have during some time developped some sheets, which relies on the same macro.
It will find the headers, and copy the columns from the selected columns.

The sheet is made to compare two different sets of data, whereas the Find function within VBA is used very often.

**My Problem**

The problem lies within the `Find` function, whereas it references the same column, with two different names, which have a slight comparison.

It happens with two columns, which has a comparison in name, to some extent, as shown below:

```
Sub CopyPasteDataLookingForHeader()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = Sheets("Put in data")

    'I'm trying to find the column header Total Lineamount within my sheet
    FindTotalLineVAT = sht.Range("1:1").Find("Total Lineamount").Address(False, False, xlA1)
    TotalLineVAT = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(FindTotalLineVAT, 1, "")

    'FindTotalLineVAT will return Cell "J1"
    'TotalLineVAT will return column "J"

    'I'm trying to find the column header Total Lineamount excl VAT within my sheet
    FindTotalLineXVAT = sht.Range("1:1").Find("Total Lineamount excl VAT").Address(False, False, xlA1)
    TotalLineXVAT = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(FindTotalLineXVAT, 1, "")

    'FindTotalLineXVAT will return Cell "J1"
    'TotalLineXVAT will return column "J"

End Sub
```

**My Goal**

I want this formula to return two different results of cell and column.
The "Find" function should return two different sets of cells, since the names are different to some extent.

Can someone explain why "Find" is not searching for the entire name, but only bits of it?

Please do let me know, your answer is very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get twice the same result as by default the `LookAt` parameter in the `Find` function is set to `xlPart`.
Try setting the `LookAt` parameter to `xlWhole` in the `Find` function as follows:

```
FindTotalLineVAT = sht.Range("1:1").Find("Total Lineamount", Lookat:=xlWhole).Address(False, False, xlA1)

FindTotalLineXVAT = sht.Range("1:1").Find("Total Lineamount excl VAT", Lookat:=xlWhole).Address(False, False, xlA1)
```

It should now work as expected.

Comment: Just for your interest `LookAt` **has no default** to `xlPart` it just uses the one that was used last before using `find`. So if you don't specify `LookAt` at all you never know what you will get.

Comment: @PatrickS If you will be using similar VBA code with `LookAt:=xlWhole` quite a bit, may I suggest adding a dummy find afterwards using `LookAt:=xlPart`. Otherwise, Excel will save your new setting and next time you try and do a find within Excel it will retrieve only cells containing exactly the search query. You may have a headache wondering why Excel is saying it can't find `Red` when there is a cell right in front of you with the value `Redgate`.

Comment: @BrownishMonster That's a good point. Defaulting to the last used is really annoying.

Comment: Did anyone already make a topic on excel uservoice about this. It just should have a default imho